# StandardAnalyzer class not found

Tags: java, lucene

I have downloaded latest Lucene 4.6.0 and [running it in netbeans](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~caim/lab/luceneEclipseNetbeans.txt).

Lucence 3.6.x version is running perfectly but the latest version cannot find `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer` and `IndexFiles.java`, showing an error in the line:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
```

The error is :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package
    org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
at org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles.<clinit>(IndexFiles.java:21)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Actually I have not found any folder `standard` in latest version.

Could any one please help me?

Answer (score 8):

You need to download lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.0.jar and put it in your classpath. It contains StandardAnalyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct location of StandardAnalyzer is : lucene_[version]/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-[version].jar
Thanks!